# Disabling memoization in Rails associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to disable all caching in a `has_one` association?

We would like to change an instance method into an association, but don't want to risk the side-effects of the association caches (such as [this](http://jerodsanto.net/2011/04/activerecord-association-caching-gotcha/)).

We would also like to eliminate it at the association level, instead of each usage, by using `(true)` (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching).

Answer (score 2):

The `:inverse_of` option (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations) should prevent stale association objects in some cases.